# Google Maps API polygon overlay

Tags: javascript, json, html, google-maps, google-api

I have been looking through some libraries and the API itself for a solution like the one apartmentlist.com uses to show parts of cities. For example when you hover over Palo Alto, Menlo Park or Redwood City, you get a nice overlay that cover that parts.

I would like to do the same thing, but have no clue how it is done.

Have found out a bit about polygons but I don't really think that is what I am looking for?

**This is what I want to achieve:**

[image: Image of what I want to achieve]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't find anything else to upvote and give you more rep...

Comment: there you go...  I found some more to up vote...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was polygons I wanted to use. They are easy to create by using the Google Maps Drawing Library.

[Google Maps Drawing Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawing#overview)